# About molecules tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a question related to atomic and molecular physics and noticed that there is a tag of "atomic physics" but not for "molecular physics". To some extent, I think that the latter is replaced by the tag "molecules", but the question is, why "molecular physics" is not used as a tag instead of "molecules"?

Questions about the physical properties of molecules should deserve a tag with a proper name.